# Name for balls of dirt made by rubbing hands

Tags: single-word-requests

When your hands are dirty, you can rub them together vigorously, and small pills of dirt and oil will form that fall away. I have an inkling that there is a name for these things, or this action, but I can’t seem to find it by searching. Is there one? If so, what is it?

Comment: Just FYI, a lot of what is in that "ball" is skin.

Comment: @Mike: Yep. When your hands don’t have anything on them (other than dead skin of course) you can still do this for that very reason.

Comment: My money's on "there is no word for something that specific".

Comment: @ParthianShot: Mine too! I think it’s very likely that I’m misremembering or confabulating, but I want to make sure in case someone says to themselves “what an idiot, that’s obviously —!”.

Comment: @Jon, I'm with Parthian Shot; I doubt you'll find a single word that can sum it up more perfectly than the wonderful phrase you've already crafted, "small pills of dirt and oil." Maybe replace the word "pills" with "globoids," which sounds nice and oily? Or "boluses"?

Comment: Generically, you could probably refer to such things as ***skin debris***.

Comment: A bolus is something that is being eaten, normally, which I hope you aren't doing with this dirt.

Comment: When I was a kid we called them "balls of dirt".  Of course that was before the InterWeb.

Comment: My mom used to call these "fribbles", which I continue to use to describe these dead-skin bits but the dictionary does not back me up. :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about dregs, smut, or crud?

> [dregs](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/dregs): a small remnant; any small quantity.
>
> [crud](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/crud): a deposit or coating of refuse or of an impure or alien substance; muck.
>
> [smut](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/smut): a speck of soot or dirt.

Comment: _Crud_ was the first word that popped into my head as well, but it doesn't necessarily mean the little pills that form when you rub your hands; it is also perfectly usable of the dirt on your hands before you rub them.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet, agreed, but I thought they were worthwhile contenders. I couldn't think of a more specific word for those grime balls.

Answer (score 0):

My grandmother used to have a horrifically racist name for these.  For whatever random reason the thought just entered my head wondering if there was a more acceptable term, and here I am, learning there's not.  I call them dirt rolls now.

Comment: Would you mind mentioning what the term was, for educational purposes? (I'm not kidding--I think it would be a valuable addition, though obviously you would recommend against using the term today.) If you can find other examples of the term being used, or discussion of it, that would be even better.

Comment: I don't know the name the OP was thinking of. According to Google, one well known insulting name for them is "nigger babies", so that might be it. Some days I swear I am tired of being human.